# Procmail not running

Tags: mutt, procmail

I'm using: Mutt-kz + Isync + msmtp + spamassassin + Procmail

Mutt-kz, Isync and msmtp are working. I cannot make procmail start automatically when mail arrives. I'm doing everything as non-root user and running Arch Linux. Procmail is installed.

Folders structure:

```
$HOME/Mail/Inbox
          /Enviados
          /Borradores
          /Spam
          /P-Spam
          /Trash
```

Mail arrives with this cronjob script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mbsync googlemail && notmuch new
```

Here's my .forward with 644 perms.

```
"|IFS=' ' && exec /usr/bin/procmail -f- || exit 75 #damian"
```

Here's my .procmailrc with 644 perms.

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
LOGFILE=$HOME/Mail/procmail.log
LOGABSTRACT=ALL
VERBOSE=YES   
DEFAULT=$HOME/Mail
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh

:0fw: spamassassin.lock
* < 512000
| /usr/bin/vendor_perl/spamc 

:0fw
| /usr/bin/vendor_perl/spamc 

:0:
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
Spam

:0:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
P-Spam
```

If I run procmail -v I get (only the important stuff):

```
procmail v3.22 2001/09/10
Locking strategies:     dotlocking, fcntl(), lockf(), flock()
Default rcfile:         $HOME/.procmailrc
Your system mailbox:    /var/spool/mail/damian
```

I I run:

```
procmail DEFAULT=/dev/null VERBOSE=yes /dev/null </dev/null
```

I get:

```
procmail: [1970] Tue Apr 21 22:16:37 2015
procmail: Rcfile: "/dev/null"
procmail: Assigning "MAILDIR=/home/damian"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/dev/null"
procmail: Opening "/dev/null"
Folder: /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any easy way to integrate Procmail into `isync` / `mbsync`.  I would go for server-side filtering, or possibly abandoning the (as such neat) idea of syncing IMAP with local folders.

With that, my original answer probably doesn't matter much, but I have preserved it below.

---

Your `.forward` file contains a syntax error.  The `damian` should be a comment `# damian` but in this day and age, unless you are running a legacy Sendmail from last century, you can just leave it out.

Using `zsh` as your shell for Procmail processing looks weird; try changing that to `/bin/sh`.  Even if you like `zsh`, you should probably prefer to avoid its features in Procmail.  Using nonstandard shells has caused hard-to-explain trouble in the past (although the bugs I have seen were with `tcsh`).

You have two `spamc` recipes.  One should suffice.  The second one should go (`spamc` itself will refuse messages which are too large, anyway), but I would also remove locking from the first one.

Your `DEFAULT` should probably be `$HOME/Mail/Inbox`, right?  You don't want mail in `$HOME/Mail` directly, do you?

Other than that, your `.procmailrc` is unremarkable.

For more help, maybe see http://iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the `.forward` error or using `zsh` would break things completely for you, but I see nothing else here. Adding some diagnostics from your `procmail.log` would certainly be a useful addition to your question if this doesn't help.

Comment: I have removed many of the recipes from procmail for the post, it's not the purpose of this question, I just want it running. procmail.log is empty, since it' s not starting.

Comment: So did you try the things at http://iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html#startup?  What's the result?

Comment: I've changed damian with #damian in the .forward file and edited the question in the end with the results you asked for. Still not working.

Comment: Not familiar with lsync and googling doesn't turn up anything useful.  Is that what's supposed to somehow deliver your email to Procmail?  Perhaps you should describe that part of your set-up in more detail.

Comment: To set-up isync I've followed the suggestions in Arch wiki [Isync-Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync). I have a channel for every folder in gmail. Synchronization is working. Are you suggesting that something should be changed in the .mbsync file?

Comment: I don't see anything in there which would deliver any message locally, and thus nothing which would trigger Procmail.  I don't think this setup has any sane chance to integrate your `.forward` file and still remain true to its goals.  See also https://www.mail-archive.com/isync-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00918.html

Comment: I haven't found anything to start procmail from isync. I saw  the link you provided some time ago. I suppose then that Isync+procmail don't work together. Thank you tripleee.

Answer (score 0):

Since `procmail` isn't used as your MDA, it won't be called.

I suggest you to work on the basis of a shell script which will be fired regularly through `cron` and will use `formail` to explicitly feed `procmail`.

Here is a skeleton for such a shell script:

```
$ cat <<eof >splitter.sh
#!/bin/sh

orig_mailbox=${HOME}/Mail/Inbox

[ -s ${orig_mailbox} ] && formail -s <${orig_mailbox} procmail ${HOME}/.procmailrc
eof
```

Of course this can only work as long as your `.procmailrc` will remove any mail from your incoming mailbox. To be sure of this I suggest to end your `.procmailrc` by a catch all rule:

```
:0
${HOME}/Mail/Received
```